# antialias in Android OpenGLES 2.0 when drawing a texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

When I draw a texture(generated from a bitmap) on SurfaceTexture using OpenGLES 2.0 (glsl shader) in Android, it turns out right when in normal size, but shows aliasing when in smaller size. Is there a way to set antialias in OpenGLES or glsl shader?

Comment: Sounds like you need to enabling mipmapping and texture filtering on your source image.

Comment: You mean `GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)` ? I did, but nothing happened.

Comment: Try GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D) after loading your source image, as well as the glTexParameterf line you posted. 
I might be wrong about the details as I don't use java bindings, and I don't know how you're loading your texture which is why I'm commenting rather than answering, but hopefully I'm giving information that might point you in the right way.